# Pass by reference Notation in C++

Tags: c++

Hi can Anyone Explain difference between the following declaration as I am new to c++:

`T& s` vs  `T & s`.

what's the difference between the above notation.

Thanks.

Comment: `Class` is not a keyword, `class` is a keyword.  If that was a typo, then there is no difference.

Comment: My apologies for that I meant to say for example int& x vs int & x what's the difference

Comment: Both are the same, you are declaring a reference to an integer.  Note that references must be initialised (or you get a compilation error).

Comment: Adding or removing white space between the tokens has no effect on the meaning.

Comment: So which function will be executed                                                                   1) ostream& operator << ( ostream& os, const Rider& r)
{
   os << "Rider name: " << r.name 
      << " Age: " << r.age
      << " Rank: " << r.rank 
      << " Weyr: " << r.weyr << endl;
   return os;
}                                                                                                               2)ofstream& operator << ( ofstream& os, const Rider& r )
{
   os << r.name << endl
      << r.age << endl
      << r.rank << endl
      << r.weyr << endl;

   return os;
}

Comment: @Anny Why are you asking about code when the answer is that there is no difference between the two declarations?

Comment: Cause this is one of the code I have to explain but my teacher insist that there is a difference '(

Comment: But still thanks for clarification.

Comment: @Anny the difference is in the **types** of parameters being passed, not the **syntax** of the reference notation. #1 works with *any* `ostream` descendant, whereas #2 *only* works with `ofstream` and descendants. `ofstream` is an `ostream` descendant. If both #1 and #2 are in scope, an `ofstream` variable will invoke #2 since it is a better match.

Comment: Got it Remy Lebeau now understand why I need these 2 functions as 1 for writing and second 1 for display

Answer (score 1):

These:

```
int &a = c;
int& a = c;
int & a = c;
int & \
a = c;
```

Are all the same. [Live example](http://ideone.com/C4AKCT)

Comment: Downvoter, an explanation would be nice ...

Comment: Not dv, but space may change the meaning in some places.`#define F()` vs `#define F    ()` for example.

Comment: @Jarod42 But that is a pre-processor token, not part of the language? But i do agree, i mean `+ =` is different to `+=`, so maybe independent is the wrong word to use.